# Adding elements in set

Tags: python, list, set, append, updating

data1: `2`

element: `3`

sorted set after adding: `['3', '2']`

data2: `4`

sorted set after updating: `[['4'], '3', '2']`

When displaying the sorted set after updating I want the output to be like
sorted set after updating: `[ 4, 3, 2]`

```
data1 = input("data1: ").split(",")
element = input("element: ")
l1 = []

for i in data1:
    l1.append(i)

l1.insert(-1, element)
print("sorted set after adding:", l1)

data2 = input("data2: ").split(",")
l1.insert(0, data2)
print("sorted set after updating:", l1)
```

Comment: `data2` is a list. If you want to insert the elements of `data2` at the beginning of `l1` you should use slice-assigment `l1[0:0] = data2` instead of `l1.insert(data2)`.

Comment: It's unnecessarily confusing that you refer to your list as a set because a set is a different data structure with different methods and semantics.

Comment: In what sense is ['3', '2'] sorted? You don't sort the list (either naturally or reversed) so in order to achieve that you'd have to scan the list to figure out where to insert the value according to its lexical order - and you're not doing that

Comment: @Stanford J Gadaga Is my answer beneficial for you..! please let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
data1=input("data1: ").split(",")
element=input("element: ")
l1=[]
for i in data1:
    l1.append(int(i))
l1.insert(-1,int(element))
l1=sorted(l1,reverse=True)
print("sorted set after adding:",l1)
data2=input("data2: ").split(",")
for i in data2:
    l1.append(int(i))
l1=sorted(l1,reverse=True)
print("sorted set after updating:",l1)
```

**Output:-**
**Your Testcase:-**

```
data1: 2
element: 3
sorted set after adding: [3, 2]
data2: 4
sorted set after updating: [4, 3, 2]
```

**Another testcase:-**

```
data1: 3,5,1
element: 4
sorted set after adding: [5, 4, 3, 1]
data2: 6,2,8
sorted set after updating: [8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You removed the `.split(',')` from `data2=input("data2: ").split(",")`. I'm not sure it's safe to assume that the OP doesn't want to allow input of comma separated values.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. Updated with the another testcase also!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat `data2` like you did with `data1`, and also use `sort()` to sort your list:

```
data1=input("data1: ").split(",")
element=input("element: ")

l1=[]
for i in data1:
    # you should parse inputs to int
    l1.append(int(i))
    
l1.insert(-1,int(element))

# we sort the list
l1.sort(reverse=True)
print("sorted set after adding:",l1)

# add the second input like you did with the first one
data2=input("data2: ").split(",")
for i in data2:
    l1.append(int(i))

l1.sort(reverse=True)
print("sorted set after updating:",l1)
```

Output:

```
data1: 1,2,3
element: 5
sorted set after adding: [5, 3, 2, 1]
data2: 4
sorted set after updating: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

based on your code when you are having this input ['3', '2'] your list would be l[0] = ['3' and l[1]= '2'], that's why you are getting a weird output.

one way to solve the problem is to parse the input to numbers while adding them into the list.